# Installation steps for Salesforce ANT migration tool (apache ANT) on Linux machine

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, ant, migration-tool

i need to install Apache ANT and Salesforce ANT migration tool on the Linux machine.

I have downloaded both zip files and installed the java JDK 11 version. How can i set up the environment variables on a Linux machine as per the steps given(i believe those steps are for windows) for ANT installation.

Are there any detailed steps to set up ANT for Linux ? i have VS code and Salesforce SFDX CLI installed on Linux machine so need to install ANT also on Linux machine.

i am doing one POC on package installation automation using metadata API, for that i need sfdx CLI, ANT .

Comment: I can't answer your question, but is there a reason you would want to use Salesforce Ant integration instead of SFDX or the new `sf` CLI? It is no longer maintained, so if possible switch to `sf` CLI (this effectively being a replacement for `sfdx`).

Comment: Hi Pil - thank you for your response, my requirement got changed we need to implement the package installation automation with apex classes. So i am check on how to call the package installation api from apex. Please let me know if you have any leads on this.

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question (if you didn't already), and perhaps close this one? Remember that there are expectations as to the asker having tried to resolve the question themselves first (so make sure to show research). For use of the full Metadata API from Apex you will need to employ something like the [FinancialForce Apex Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) package.

Answer (score 0):

After my research i came to know that we can implement this through metadata api i am further investigating this. https://andyinthecloud.com/2013/06/23/look-ma-no-hands-automating-install-and-uninstall-of-packages/